# I have concerns on the highlighted part of this text "come in near last in my age group"

Tags: word-meaning

> I like to be outdoors, pick on people my size, and read books. I'm a patent lawyer, and relatively good-looking for a nerd. I love Ironman triathlons, **but usually come in near last in my age group**. I can fly a single-engine plane.
>
> I like a man with a big brain (not head) and strong legs. Ideally, someone who understands "the road less traveled," and the value of a patent. If you also happen to have a fast bicycle (not the motorized kind), dabble in swordfighting, or have mastered cartography, then you are my man.

I think word like **it** is missing between **but** and **usually**, so that it could be paraphrased as " it ( Iron Man the movie) , is the last choise for people my age. Am I right?
My main concern actually has to with if this is a way of speeking casually or perhaps some word is missing from her speech. I mean does she know that a word **it** has been missed here?

Comment: "Ironman triathlon" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironman_Triathlon) has really nothing to do with "Iron Man" (the movie).

Answer (score 3):

The writer is not referring to a movie. Ironman triathlons are exceedingly gruelling sporting events, and "ironman" has no connection to the comic in this context.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironman_Triathlon for more details.

The writer means "I love these events, but **I** usually come in near last in my age group." It is perfectly acceptable if slightly informal English to leave "I" out in this sentence.